# Plot percentages in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have a data set in the following form 2 columns, `x` and `s`:

```
x<-c(9,13,6,8,10,4,14,8,11,7,9,7,16,9,9,11,13,15,13,10,11,6)
s<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

For which I want to plot the percentages of (success = 1) for each level of `x`.
There are many more rows with the same score for `x` and in various cases the `s=1` or `s=0`.

Thank you so much for your time.

The plot made using Daniel's aid is this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the aggregate function and mean functions `aggregate(s ~ x, FUN = mean)`. This can be plotted with `plot(aggregate(s ~ x, FUN = mean), type = "h")`

Comment: Thank you so much! That really worked. Is there a way to  make the X axis be more informative with more scores for example instead of going by 5?

Comment: You can specify the delineation of the axis in plot using the axis function (see documentation). If you want complete control, turn off both when plotting plot(x, y, axes=F) then add them in by hand.